# API Database Connection Issue

Tags: c#, api, iis

I am attempting to create a new web api for my company and am running into an issue with permissions.

First, the api is hosted on one server and it needs to access a database on another server. The app pool is using ApplicationPoolIdentity as it's identity.

When I run the api from Visual Studio, it is able to access the database on the other server. Incidently, I made sure that my login doesn't have access to that server. Instead I am forcing the api to use a connection string from the web.config file that contains a username and password. I am able to pull back information just fine.

When I put the api into IIS on my machine, I get the error 'Login failed for user Domain\username' any time I try to get information to return from the API. Is there any reason that Visual Studio would allow this to work, but IIS keeps trying to login to the database server with my machine account instead of using the connection string in the web.config file? I am trying to figure out how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It seems that my connection string was being modified in three different places in the program. At one point one of my team members had it coded to pull the machine as the user instead of using my connection string. Once I updated and removed redundant code I was able to make the connection between machines without having to use a domain account.